# What does execl do if it can't find the command?

Tags: linux, shell, exec, os.execl

I already read the man page and did some googling. Couldn't find anything. Say I run execl with a path argument that doesn't actually contain the program specified in arg[0].

What will it do?

Comment: What's so bad about trying it? What's the worst that could possibly happen?

Comment: Agree - worst possible case would be an OS reinstall ;-)

Comment: The man page says "The `execl()`, `execle()`, `execlp()`, `execvp()`, and `execvP()` functions may fail and set `errno` for any of the errors specified for the library functions `execve(2)` and `malloc(3)`."  Did you look at those man pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns -1 and sets `errno` (just try it!). It sets `errno` depending on the exact problem encountered.

From [the man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html):

> #### Errors
>
> `EACCES` Search permission is denied on a component of the path prefix of
>                 `filename` or the name of a script interpreter.  (See also
>                 path_resolution(7).)
>
> `ENAMETOOLONG`
>                 filename is too long.
>
> `ENOENT` The file `filename` or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist, or a
>                 shared library needed for file or interpreter cannot be found.
>
> `ENOTDIR`
>                 A component of the path prefix of `filename` or a script or ELF
>                 interpreter is not a directory.